# Подключение curl к проекту

Tags: c++, visual-studio, curl, visual-studio-2015

Есть скомпилированная библиотека curl. Нужно подключить ее к visual studio, чтобы можно было использовать ее прямо из проекта, без лишних надстроек?

Comment: Можно чуть подробнее, что означает "без лишних надстроек"?

Comment: то есть я хочу просто зайти в студию, создать проект, подключить нужные библиотеки и все

Comment: если `curl` собран в той же версии студии, с теми же настройками, то проблем быть не должно

Comment: я не знаю как подключить саму собранную библиотеку к проекту

Comment: Самый брутальный способ - перетяните мышкой в дерево проекта

Answer (score 1):

Подключаете header-файл

`#include <curl/curl.h>`

Подключаете файл библиотеки

`#pragma comment ( lib, "путь/к/скомпилированной/библиотеке/libcurl.lib" )`

В препроцессорные определения в свойствах проекта добавляете

`CURL_STATICLIB`

Пользуете.

> P.S.: Для отладки, при необходимости, подключается и используется
>   отладочная версия либы - libcurld.lib